# How can I make a random function in JavaScript without using the Math.random function?

Tags: javascript, random

I want to generate a random number using 0 and 1.

I've written the code, but the larger the number, the larger the error range. How can I write better code?

My current code

Code to generate 0 and 1

```
const get_zero_or_one = () => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (2))
}
```

Code to generate a random number using the above code

The code I want to change is this code.

```
const RandomResult = (max_number) => {
    let answer = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < max_number -1; i++) {
        answer += get_zero_or_one()
    }
    return answer
}
```

The condition is not to use the Math.random function.
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "the larger the number, the larger the error range"? do you have errors using `Math.random`? And why the condition not to use it? A code challenge or some obscure homeworks question?

Comment: `const get_zero_or_one = () => 0;` (I chose 0 randomly, a variant on https://xkcd.com/221/)

Comment: hmm.. 
In the get_zero_or_one described above, we want to use the Math.random function and create a random function using this get_zero_or_one.

Comment: It is a code challenge found in Korea. The method I presented is that I heard that there are good ways to think that losing the meaning of random values ​​in the case of a larger number (ex: 100, 1000).

Comment: Typical approach is to use a Linear Congruential Generator, as long as you're not using it for cryptographic security: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator

Comment: You could look into this book The Art of Computer Programming, Volume 2: Seminumerical Algorithms from Donald E Knuth for various algorithm available to generate random numbers.

Answer (score -2):

The idea is simple i get the current date by `new Date()` and use get its milliseconds and then check if its even then return `0` else `1`

```
const get_zero_or_one = () => {
  return (((new Date()).getMilliseconds()) % 2 === 0) ? 0 : 1;
}
```

Comment: `for (var l = 0; l < 100; l += 1) console.log(get_zero_or_one())` =>   `24(0), 14(1), 17(0) 17(1) 15(0) 13(1)`... IOW: not very random.. :)

Comment: @Keith you are right.